# Is there a tool to get the GPS data from a Wordpress blog on a map?

Tags: map

There is a guy biking through the world.

He is writing a wordpress blog about it.

Most of his posts have a GPS coordinate at the bottom.

I was wondering if it would be possible to draw a (red) line on a (google?) map perhaps.

So you can follow the route this guy is going.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Currently it's "too broad" and "do this work for me for free", which are both close reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what level you want to work.
You can try exploring Leaflet. It's a really powerful mapping tool. 
I think Wordpress might have some tools to help you work with it.
See here:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/leaflet-maps-marker/

You could also look into KML and such, but it's time consuming.